# How to set Spyder as default program/app to open (.py) Python file?

Tags: python, macos, editor

How to set Spyder as default program for Python file? This question has been asked over and over in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24643474/1681375) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33817046/1681375). I looked around, there still isn't an answer.

I want to click on a .py file, and open it in Spyder. Instead of, opening Sypder from Terminal, then go to File > open. I'm using a Mac.

This question was asked as early as 2013. It's now 2018!

Comment: your question is different. Other questions address only windows. Macintosh is a different beast.

Answer (score 1):

### Steps:

- Download the [spyder-mac-app.zip archive](https://github.com/sharmalabs/spyder/blob/master/scripts/spyder-mac-app.zip). Unarchive it to
  `/Applications`
- Edit the `/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/MacOS/Spyder` file to launch the right environment of Spyder, e.g.:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  $HOME/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/bin/spyder $@
  ```
- Launch Spyder from Finder to verify that Finder is launching as expected.
- [Install duti](https://superuser.com/questions/273756/how-to-change-default-app-for-all-files-of-particular-file-type-through-terminal) and run `duti -s org.spyder .py all`
- Right click any `.py` file in Finder, click `Get Info` In `Open with` menu, select `Other` and navigate to `'Applications`. Select `Spyder`, Press `Add` and Click on `Change All` in Info menu.

Comment: Is the `duti` step necessary? I skipped it and it seemed to work fine...?

Answer (score -3):

Here is the rundown (seen here: [Change Default App For File On Mac](https://www.imore.com/how-set-mac-app-default-when-opening-file)):

1. Right Click File
2. Click Get Info
3. Click Open With Dropdown
4. Choose The App
5. Click Change All
6. If Asked Click Continue

Comment: good call about giving the rundown, else it would have been a link only answer, which is bad.

Comment: It does not work. Spyder is not in in drop down menu in step 4. I even did: right clicked Python file > open with > other , and then, enable > All applications. Spyder is still in light gray. Does not work!

Comment: Oh, sorry I don't use spyder I just thought it would be like most applications. I'll try to take a closer look today.